# Are there prerequisites to "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond" By Robin Hartshorne?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I saw that the "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond"  By Robin Hartshorne seemed like a good book to learn geometry. Is this text suitable for someone who doesn't have a lot of geometry knowledge ? Thank you

Comment: Did you try picking it up and reading the preface or introduction? Text book authors are usually good at describing the book's target audience and their desired background.

Comment: From the preface: "In recent years, I have been teaching a junior--senior-level course on the classical geometries. This book has grown out of that teaching experience. I assume only high-school geometry and some abstract algebra."

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. Sadly, I don't know abstract alhebra...